# What is Big O of n^2 x logn?

Tags: big-o

Is it n^2 x logn or n^3? I know both of these answers act as upper bounds, I’m just torn between choosing a tighter but more complex bound (option 1), or a “worse” yet simpler bound (option 2).
Are there general rules to big O functions such as big O functions can never be too complex/a product of two functions?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with `O(n^2 * log n)`. If it's accurate, use it. Generally, use the lowest bound that is accurate regardless of complexity. Merge Sort is famously `O(n * log n)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already seem to have an excellent understanding of the fact that big-O notation is an *upper bound*, and also that a function with runtime complexity `n^2 logn` falls in both `O(n^2 logn)` and `O(n^3)`, so I'll spare you the mathematics of that. It's immediately clear (from the fact that `n^2 logn` is in `O(n^3)`) that `O(n^2 logn)` is a subset of `O(n^3)`, so the former is a at least as good of a bound. It turns out to be a strictly tighter bound (that can be seen with some basic algebra), which is a definite point in its favor. I do understand your concern about the complexity of bounds, but I wouldn't worry about that. Mathematically, it's best to favor accuracy over simplicity, when the two are at odds, and `n^2 logn` is not that complex of an expression. So in my mind, `O(n^2 logn)` is a much better bound to state.

Other examples of similar or greater complexity:

- As indicated in the comments, [merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) and [quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) have average time complexity `O(n logn)`.
- [Interpolation search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation_search) has an average time complexity of `O(log logn)`.
- The average case of [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) is stated on Wikipedia to be the absolute mouthful `O(E + V log(E/V) log(V))`.